# Acessar dados e alterar csv ou txt com python

Tags: python, csv, ciência-de-dados

Eu tenho esse script que faz tratativas de dados, peguei alguns exemplos da internet mas não consegui acessar os dados, antes de gravar em csv eu preciso modificar alguns campos, por exemplo, o campo data, está separado por ponto(24.03.2020) e preciso passar salvar (24/03/2020), pensei em fazer replace mas ainda não consegui acessar os dados, poderiam me ajudar?

```
    with open("ZV_R0051.txt", "r", encoding="UTF-16") as ler, open("teste.csv", mode='w', encoding='UTF-16') as gravar:
        next(ler)
        next(ler)
        gravar.writelines(['data_puxada;','centro;','atribuicao;','ped_pca;','transporte;','fornecimento;','codigo_material;','descr_produto;','descr_status_pedido;','quantidade;','hora_puxada;','cliente;','cliente_sap;','numero_nota_fiscal;','data_inicio_carregamento;','hora_inicio_carregamento;','dt_termino_carregamento;','hora_termino_carregamento;','numeroov_pedtransf;','can_distrib;','tipo_operacao;','tipo_operacao;'])
        gravar.write('\n')
        next(ler)
        next(ler)

        for linha in ler:
            if  len(linha.strip()) > 0 and len(linha.strip("਍ഀ").strip()) > 0:
                linha = linha.rstrip()
                gravar.writelines(linha.replace('\t',';').strip()[:-2].rstrip()[1:])
                gravar.write('\n')
                print(linha)

except AttributeError:
    print("Erro")
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui,

adicionei .replace(".",'/',2).replace(".","",10)

onde está o numero informa em qual coluna eu quero alterar.
Então ficou assim

gravar.writelines(linha.replace('\t',';').strip()[:-2].rstrip()[1:].replace(".",'/',2).replace(".","",10))